# How to get some rows from a DataFrame to build another DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Assumed my DataFrame 'candidates' looks as follow:

```
                                   HnL   close   r_value  sector_code  
Equity(36742 [TREE])               1.0  279.25  0.974858        103.0   
Equity(16820 [TTWO])               1.0  118.89  0.973719        311.0   
Equity(45521 [RNG])                1.0   47.20  0.972306        311.0   
Equity(49242 [PYPL])               1.0   77.70  0.985572        103.0   
Equity(25339 [ISRG])               1.0  393.76  0.985117        206.0   
Equity(8613 [CHDN])                1.0  217.30  0.989951        102.0
```

The most left column is the index.

What I want is: I will take out some rows to build another DataFrame. I use the following to get the row:

```
for index, row in candidates.iterrows():
    ... do some calculation here,
    ... if fulfills my criteria, add this row to build 
    ... the new DataFrame with the same index
```

Assumed the 1., 3. and 6. rows fulfill my criteria, after rebuld the new DataFrame, it should look like as follow:

```
                                    HnL   close   r_value  sector_code  
Equity(36742 [TREE])               1.0  279.25  0.974858        103.0   
Equity(45521 [RNG])                1.0   47.20  0.972306        311.0   
Equity(8613 [CHDN])                1.0  217.30  0.989951        102.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list to store the index of all of the rows that you want to add to the new dataframe, then use `.loc` to subset out those rows.

```
keep_rows = list()
for index, row in candidates.iterrows():
    # define a condition that is either True or False based on row values
    # for example, "condition = row['close'] > 200"
    if condition:
        keep_rows.append(index)
new_df = candidates.loc[keep_rows,:]
```